# JTable listen for entering editing mode

Tags: java, swing, jtable

This is a pretty simple question, but I couldn't find an answer nonetheless (please forgive my clumsy searching ...).
There's a Jtable with editable cells and I want to detect when a cell is being entered for editing (for instance by double-clicking). How would I do this?

Comment: @sers, the answer was marked as a duplicate and my original answer deleted. As a result of my above comment it appears the question was reopened, but my answer was not restored. I just added my answer back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a `PropertyChangeListener` to the `JTable`:

```
//
//  Implement the PropertyChangeListener interface
//
    @Override
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent e)
    {
        //  A cell has started/stopped editing

        if ("tableCellEditor".equals(e.getPropertyName()))
        {
            if (table.isEditing())
                // code for editing started;
            else
                // code for editing stopped;
        }
    }
```